# Create a dataframe with zeros given a input in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
dataknow <- data.frame(id = c("BAL","BEL"),
                       signal_a = c(1,2),
                       signal_b = c(4,3),
                       signal_c = c(2,1),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  id signal_a signal_b signal_c
1 BAL        1        4        2
2 BEL        2        3        1
```

I want to convert it to a diagonal like dataframe. This is the expected output:

```
id    signal_a    signal_b    signal_c
BAL   1           0           0
BAL   0           4           0
BAL   0           0           2
BEL   2           0           0
BEL   0           3           0
BEL   0           0           1
```

I tried this approach but I'm kind of stuck:

```
dataknow %>% 
  mutate(repm = 3) %>% 
  uncount(repm)

    id signal_a signal_b signal_c
1   BAL        1        4        2
1.1 BAL        1        4        2
1.2 BAL        1        4        2
2   BEL        2        3        1
2.1 BEL        2        3        1
2.2 BEL        2        3        1
```

Please, any help in dplyr will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `pmap` to loop over the numeric column, create the `diag`, `unnest` and `rename` the columns at the end

```
library(dplyr) # 1.0.0
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
dataknow %>% 
     # // pmap over the rows
     transmute(id, new = pmap(select(., where(is.numeric)), 
      # // convert to diag
         ~ as.data.frame(diag(c(...))))) %>% 
     # // expand the list column with unnest
     unnest(c(new)) %>%
     rename_at(-1, ~ names(dataknow)[-1])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  id    signal_a signal_b signal_c
#  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 BAL          1        0        0
#2 BAL          0        4        0
#3 BAL          0        0        2
#4 BEL          2        0        0
#5 BEL          0        3        0
#6 BEL          0        0        1
```

---

Or with `c_across`

```
dataknow %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    summarise(id, signal = diag(c_across(where(is.numeric)))) %>%   
    do.call(data.frame, .)
```

---

Or another option with `recast`

```
reshape2::recast(dataknow, id.var = 'id', 
         seq_len(prod(dim(dataknow[-1])))+ id ~ variable,
         fill = 0)[-1] %>% 
     arrange(id)
#   id signal_a signal_b signal_c
#1 BAL        1        0        0
#2 BAL        0        4        0
#3 BAL        0        0        2
#4 BEL        2        0        0
#5 BEL        0        3        0
#6 BEL        0        0        1
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, id = dataknow$id, 
   apply(dataknow[-1], 1, function(x) as.data.frame(diag(x)))))
```

Comment: One of my summer assignments is to update my knowledge in dplyr. I gotta pick up new functions from version 1.0. `c_across()` is surely one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun, the best part of your answer is that I learn new concepts like `do.call` or the new `c_across` from dplyr. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Get the data in long format, create a row number and get the data back in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataknow %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_wider(values_fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
   select(-row)

#    id    signal_a signal_b signal_c
#  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 BAL          1        0        0
#2 BAL          0        4        0
#3 BAL          0        0        2
#4 BEL          2        0        0
#5 BEL          0        3        0
#6 BEL          0        0        1
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, you know, your answer worked fine, perhaps the part I struggle with was `list(value = 0)` but finally I found the why in the help section. Have a great day!